# Relationship (edge) in Neo4j is not being created

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo

So I am trying to load the movieLens dataset into a neo4j graph. There are three nodes: USER, MOVIE, and GENRE and two edges: Has_rated and Is_Genre. I have successfully loaded all three nodes and the Is_genre relationship. But I am having a very hard time creating the relationship for Has_rated. When I run the query to create the Has_rated relationship nothing happens. It compiles and I am not getting an error but I am get no response. Here is the query I am running (I am using py2neo):

```
statement3 = ("MATCH (u:USER{id:{A}}) "
    "MATCH (m:MOVIE{movie_id:{C}}) MERGE (u)-[r:Has_rated{rating:{B}}]->(m) RETURN r")

for r,row in rating.iterrows() :
    # Retrieve "User" and "Movie" nodes, and create relationship with the corresponding rating as property
    graph.run(statement3, {"A": str(row.loc['user_id']), "C": str(row.loc['item_id']), "B": str(row.loc['rating'])})
```

Do you guys have any idea why this is?

Comment: Can you log in your code the statement3 + its parameters ? I don't see any error on your queries, but perhaps you have the user_id (or an other field) as an `Integer` instead of a `String`

Comment: What do you mean by logging statement 3 + its parameters? Sorry I don't quite understand your question because I thought I was using parameters? 

Also, since I type casted all of these values to strings shouldn't that not be an issue?

Comment: Yes you are using parameters, and yes you cast data to string. But what about the data in the db ? Are they also in String ? 
If this query is not working it's due to one of the `MATCH` that return nothing, so you need to test them

Comment: Thank you so much. I typed checked the actual data in the db and saw that it was int64 rather than int. Really appreciate your help!